# bash "vi mode" search command line (not history buffer)

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, sh

When working in bash - if I am in "vi" mode, I can use `?` or `/` to "search".

However, this appears to search the *history buffer*. If I am working with a (very) long command line, I would like to be able to search for things on the (same) command line - (like it would do in vi itself).

Is there any way to do this??

Comment: Not really. You can use `fx` and `Fx` to jump to the next/previous "x" character, and the `;` to repeat that jump. For really complicated command lines, use `v` to do your editing in your editor.

Comment: Oooo.... I didn't know about "v" - much thanks! :)